# How to hide SQL scripts from Liquibase in the console?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

In my Spring boot project, I am using `Liquibase` as version control for my database. Each time when I'm running my project I see the body of all my scripts in the console (Intellij IDEA or Terminal).

Is there any possibility to remove these scripts from console logs? It could be done via properties or bean.

I tried to set

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

but I didn't work obviously. This property is not related to `Liquibase`. I also checked the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-migration-properties but I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spring-Boot 1.2.4 you can disable logging with properties ([Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2916)) :

```
logging.level.liquibase=off
```

If you just want to remove the SQL part and still see something like `Table MY_TABLE created.`, then just remove the executor :

```
logging.level.liquibase.executor=off
```